# API for service-to-service communication in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, rest, kubernetes, containers, microservices

I'm K8s newbie building 2 services, service A and service B, in a K8s cluster. Service A needs to call service B as part of service A's code. What are my options in terms of the API should I have for service B? Is a REST API, e.g., built using Python Flask, an option typically used for this kind of service-to-service communication within a K8s cluster? What other options do I have?

Comment: Asking for the "best" option without specifying a clear metric is almost always opinion-based. --- The question - as is - is not answerable. The "right" communication technique heavily depends on how the services interact with each other (e.g. synchronously vs. asynchronously) and what the business case is.

Comment: @Turing85 Point taken. I'm a newbie and I edited the question. Right now, I don't know what my options are, so I'm looking for that so that I can choose one that fits my scenario.

Comment: HTTP APIs are certainly common enough; so are message-oriented systems like RabbitMQ or Kafka.  Anything that communicates over TCP will probably work fine.